# How to check user scrolling to left or right?

Tags: jquery

How to check user scrolling to left or right?

below code is what I tried but not work....

```
$('.inner').scroll(function(){
    console.log('scroll');
    ol = $('.inner').scrollLeft();
    if(ol > $('.inner').scrollLeft()){
        //  console.log('right');
        //  ol = $('.inner').scrollLeft();
    }else{
        //  console.log('left');
        //  ol = $('.inner').scrollLeft();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried another approach for that issue, you can find it running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/T9ehs/2/).

What I did is the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function($)
    {
        var lastLeftLocation = 0;

        $('.inner').scroll(
            function(e)
            {               
                if(lastLeftLocation > $(this).scrollLeft())
                {
                    console.log('It goes left');
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log('It goes right');
                }

                lastLeftLocation     =    e.currentTarget.scrollLeft;
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your HTML markup looks like, but you'll have to save `scrollLeft` of the container and compare it on scroll. I also added some logic to detect when scrolling start and end.

```
var container = $('.outer');
var initVal = container.scrollLeft();
var isScrolling = false;
container.scroll(function(e){
    var curVal = container.scrollLeft();
    if (!isScrolling) {
        $(window).one("mouseup", function(e){
            console.log("Stopped scrolling at", container.scrollLeft());
            isScrolling = false;
        });
        console.log("Started scrolling at", curVal);
    }    
    if (curVal === initVal) return;
    if (curVal > initVal) {
        console.log("Scrolling right");
    } else {
        console.log("Scrolling left");
    }
    initVal = curVal;
    isScrolling = true;
});
```

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Rusy/4/).