# detect mouse scroll on an item which not scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an item image tag, I try to know how to detect user scroll on this image even it not scrollable?
and after that I will check to left or right like https://stackoverflow.com/a/17312647 then I can call ajax change image url

```
$('img').scroll(function(){
    console.log('scroll');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wheel` event appears to be the standard way.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/wheel

You will probably be interested in the `deltaX` property.

Before `wheel` became standard, I was listening for `mousewheel` events for Chrome, and `DOMMouseScroll` events for Firefox:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMMouseScroll

but I don't know if they can catch horizontal scroll events.

Answer (score 1):

Here is My Way To Do that:

Create a Variable `isOvered` To display whether the Mouse is on Image.

In your `img` tag add `OnMouseOver="isOvered=true;" OnMouseOut="isOvered=false;"`

And bind Scroll Events (`mousewheel` or `DOMMouseScroll`) to body with checking that whether mouse is on `img` or not.

```
var isOvered=false;
function displaywheel(e){
var evt=window.event || e;
var delta=evt.detail? evt.detail*(-120) : evt.wheelDelta; 
if(isOvered){
if(delta<0)
{
//"Scroll Down On IMG Occured"
}
if(delta>0)
{
//"Scroll UP On IMG"
}
}
//delta returns +120 when wheel is scrolled up, -120 when down
}
var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel";  
if(document.attachEvent) document.attachEvent("on"+mousewheelevt, displaywheel);
else if (document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener(mousewheelevt, displaywheel, false);
```

Hope It helps you. Cheers :)!!